# Save an image in Figma

Tags: figma

I (not a terribly creative type) have created an image in Figma from several geometric shapes.

I would now like to save that image as a PNG.

"Save local" gives me a .fig file with no options otherwise.

The [official exports page](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040028114-Guide-to-exports-in-Figma) just tells me what a PNG is.

Other articles have lead me to do a File -> Export, after having to set export properties on each object, but that exports each individual shape as its own file.

Is there a "save image" button? Am I just blind?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Select the artboard, then Export. [See tutorial here](https://youtu.be/ZpCz59lGNE4?t=63)

Answer (score 1):

Select the objects you want to export into a single image and wrap them in a group (Cmd/Ctrl + G) or frame (Cmd/Ctrl + Alt + G), then add export properties by clicking “+” in the Export section in the properties panel on the right and click the Export button.

This video might help too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpG3foCWX-E